# Setting the domain in the AuthSession cookie for CouchDB

Tags: authentication, couchdb

When using cookie based authentication in CouchDB, the domain appears to be set to the domain of the host; *foo.com* for example. If we wish to access this session from a subdomain; *bar.foo.com* for example, this will fail.

From my limited experience with managing cookies, it appears that if you set the domain to *.foo.com* (notice the leading dot `.`), then you can access these cookies on subdomains.

Is it possible to change the domain that CouchDB uses when setting the cookie to include the leading dot?

Comment: After some more digging, the domain isn't actually set to anything, so it defaults to the domain of the host.  The question still applies though -- can you set the domain for AuthSession Cookie in couchDB?

Comment: I know that this is a really old issue, it still seems to be unresolved but in 2013 an issue was opened in CouchDB's tracker https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1959. I'll try to draft a PR for it.

Comment: Partially same problem, how do you solved it? In my case I got coockie from example.com/mydemo/_session, but it don't work on example.com/mydemo/db/

Answer (score 0):

From couch >= 2 ( tested on 2.2 myself ) you can add this to your configuration fille

`[couch_httpd_auth]
cookie_domain = foo.com`